# Can I connect an HDMI display to raspberry pi with Raspbian OS lite (doesn't have desktop)?

Tags: raspbian, hdmi, display, gui

I am currently working an a project with raspberry pi 4 and I need to display a GUI using PyQt5
The problem is the Raspbian OS lite doesn't have desktop (I installed it to optimize the resources ), and I need to display the GUI on a 5 inch HDMI display screen

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding A Desktop Environment To Raspbian/Raspberry Pi OS Lite](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/119422/adding-a-desktop-environment-to-raspbian-raspberry-pi-os-lite)

Answer (score 2):

You could also try and run the Qt5 application through the frame buffer, instead of through a windowing system. I have been happily running my application this way. It skips the requirement of a desktop environment and windowing system, which makes it boot faster and also feels more embedded. See: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/embedded-linux.html

Without a windowing system, you would only be able to show one window at a time. Which usually is not a big problem in embedded situations, although keep this in mind if you need to show more than one window at the same time for your application.

You'll have to make sure that the `EGLFS` or `linuxfb` plugins for Qt5 are in your compilation of Qt5.

You can then run your custom Qt5 application with the `-platform` argument. I start my PyQt5 application with a bash script as follows:
`python3 main.py -platform linuxfb`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you need QT for your app you will need to run X11 or wayland. You don’t have to run a full desktop and you can run X with limited resources.